# splitting and concatenating strings from multiple rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame 'df':

| Code | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 124 | "grey box" |
| 235 | "yellow candle" |
| 124 | "large box" |
| 236 | " blue suitcase" |
| 235 | "fancy candle" |
| 124 | " large box" |

The plan here is to get another data frame by grouping existing data by Code, concatenating the strings for a specific Code group, splitting it into words, and then getting the unique words in the string which will be then used to fill the value column for each Code in the new data frame.

My expected result would look something like this:

| Code | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 124 | 'large','grey','box' |
| 235 | 'fancy','yellow','candle' |
| 124 | 'large','grey','box' |
| 236 | 'blue','suitcase' |
| 235 | 'fancy','yellow','candle' |
| 124 | 'large','grey','box' |

I have tried something like this :

```
def find_unique(series):
    value = series.str.split().apply(pd.Series).stack().unique()
    return value
df_new = df.groupby('Code')['Value'].transform(lambda x:find_unique(x))
```

Comment: Can you show the other data input with the codes and the additional words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can [`str split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to convert the strings into a list of words. [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) the series [`groupby unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html) to get the unique values per code, then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to the DataFrame:

```
df = df[['Code']].join(
    df['Value'].str.split().explode().groupby(df['Code']).unique(),
    on='Code'
)
```

`df`:

```
   Code                    Value
0   124       [grey, box, large]
1   235  [yellow, candle, fancy]
2   124       [grey, box, large]
3   236         [blue, suitcase]
4   235  [yellow, candle, fancy]
5   124       [grey, box, large]
```

We can also convert back to a string if needed using [`str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) and also programmatically join back to all columns except `value` ([`Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html)):

```
df = df[
    df.columns.difference(['Value'])  # Select Columns except Value
].join(
    df['Value'].str.split().explode()
        .groupby(df['Code']).unique()
        .str.join(', '),  # Convert List to String
    on='Code'
)
```

`df`:

```
   Code                  Value
0   124       grey, box, large
1   235  yellow, candle, fancy
2   124       grey, box, large
3   236         blue, suitcase
4   235  yellow, candle, fancy
5   124       grey, box, large
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Code': [124, 235, 124, 236, 235, 124],
    'Value': ['grey box', 'yellow candle', 'large box', 'blue suitcase',
              'fancy candle', 'large box']
})
```